# How to sum all data from selected items in a box when clicked?

Tags: jquery, attributes, sum

I want a div box to display the prices of all the selected items separately and the sum of prices of items that are selected.

I have this to display the box with the selected products and the sum of prices:

```
<div id="selectedProductList">
    <ul>
        <li>selected product…</li>
        <li>selected product…</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="priceTotal">xyz $</div>
```

And the data with the product name and price in a select and input fields:

```
<select class="websiteProductList" name"product1">
    <option data-price="29.99" data-name="Product 1" value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option data-price="39.00" data-name="Product 1 with special" value="0">Product1 with special</option>
</select>

<input class="websiteProductList" type="radio" name="product2" data-name="Product 2" data-price="49.99">
<input class="websiteProductList" type="radio" name="product3" data-name="Product 3" data-price="59.99">
```

I have this Code:

```
$('.websiteProductList').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {            
            price = $(this).data('price');
            productName = $(this).data('name');
            sum += price;
            $('#selectedProductList > ul').append('<li>' + productName + '</li>');
        }
    });
    $('#priceTotal').text(sum);
});
```

But it dosn't work. My knowledge is unfortunately also very limited with JavaScript. Because you can see it immediately, probably the code is so bad that he would never work anyway. Unfortunately I can not go any further. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: can I know what is the reason you have kept the price in the data attribute? You can make the price as value know..... any reason?

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran 
In the results list i would like to get the total sum and the list of the product names of the selected products. I thought this would be easier with the data attributes, since it could be accessed differently.

Comment: ok you have two types of selecting the product 1.with radio button, 2. with drop-down any other method you will use, eg: checkbox,text-box multiple select drop-down some else.......

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran Correct. I have only radio buttons and drop-downs. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code its works fine for me.

```
<div id="selectedProductList">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
<div id="priceTotal">xyz $</div>
<select class="websiteProductList" name"product1">
<option data-price="29.99" data-name="Product 1" value="1">Product 1</option>
<option data-price="39.00" data-name="Product 1 with special" value="0">Product1 with special</option>
</select>
<input class="websiteProductList" type="radio" name="product2" data-name="Product 2" data-price="49.99">
<input class="websiteProductList" type="radio" name="product3" data-name="Product 3" data-price="59.99">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var sum=0;
$('.websiteProductList').change(function() {
```

var price=0;var productName='';

$(this).each(function() {
        var parentlocal=$(this);

```
    if(parentlocal.find("option:selected").length>0){
     price=parentlocal.find("option:selected").data('price');
     productName=parentlocal.find("option:selected").data('name');
     parentlocal.find("option:selected").attr('disabled', true);
    sum = parseFloat(sum+price);
    $('#selectedProductList > ul').append('<li>' + productName + '</li>');
    }
});
var radio_price=$(this).data('price');
var radio_productName=$(this).data('name');
if(radio_price){
         price=radio_price;
     productName=radio_productName;
    sum = parseFloat(sum+price);
    $('#selectedProductList > ul').append('<li>' + productName + '</li>');
         }
$('#priceTotal').text(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
});
```

If you find any difficulties reply.

Comment: Wow! You are great. This works fantastic.

Is there still a chance to avoid double values? So, i have the radio button to select the product and one radio button to remove. When i click the radio button to remove, the value is also listed as li-element. It would be great if the value removed from the list and sum. Same with the selection field. After clicking, it is deactivated, but there is no way to undo error entries.

Comment: how did you deselect the radio button. You have 2 different name for radio button right, then u can't deselect the radio button once you select.